# .htaccess rewrite base url for Wordpress

Tags: .htaccess

Ok sorry if this has been asked before but I could not find a working solution. I am using wordpress multisite. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Currently the domain http://mynew.com/ redirects (via my hosting co.) to one of the sites on my wordpress multisite installation as follows http://myold.com/subsite/

But I want to hide/swap the urls as follows, http://myold.com/subsite becomes http://mynew.com and all links that follow (eg. http://myold.com/subsite/another-link becomes http://mynew.com/another-link) without breaking.

I tried this in my .htaccess file which rewrote the url successfully however the links did not work and returned 404 errors.

```
RewriteRule    ^subsite/(.+)  http://mynew.com/$1  [R,L]
```

Hope that makes sense, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will get you a 404 error, you redirected the request from the old site to the new site, but the new site does not contain the requested pages, so it through you a 404, what you need to do is to redirect from the new site back to the old site **INTERNALY** (that means without changing the browser address bar), but this requires your new site to work as a proxy server, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: thanks for the url Yazmat, I'm having a read but its quite in depth, appreciate any code samples.

Comment: ok thanks Yazmat, is it necessary to setup a proxy even if the domains are on the same server with the same name servers?

Comment: sorry, I can't answer that question, I never tried it before (But I suppose it is necessary since it is not the same domain)